# django-taggit add tags form field in DetailView

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-taggit

I'd like to add a single form input field to a `DetailView` that will append tags to my model. I'm not sure if I need a separate view for that, or I can simply add a form. Using **django-bootstrap3**, I have the following:

```
<div class="row">
    <form action="add-tag" method="post"
                    enctype=multipart/form-data>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.media }}
        {% bootstrap_field form.tags show_label=False %}
        <input type="submit" value="{% trans "submit" %}"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

forms.py:

```
class MyModelAddTagsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.MyModel
        fields = ('tags',)
```

I get the error:

```
BootstrapError at /someurl/1/view

Parameter "field" should contain a valid Django BoundField.
```

I'm not sure what else I exactly need. A view and url or modifying my `DetailView`? Or using an `UpdateView` instead?

Comment: have you added `tags = TaggableManager()` to your model?

Comment: @doru Yes my model has tags and they are viewable. I tried an UpdateView that mimics my DetailView. I could use that in place, though I'm not sure if that's the best way, or how to have a field that doesn't show current values but appends new values on submit.